# Prevent FireFox using file:///c:/windows/ to open the path

Tags: firefox, citrix

I'm trying to help a project team lock down terminal services, in particular FireFox and Chrome open file paths from the browser.

We have successfully locked IE from opening the path using Citrix WEM profile manager, but FF and Chrome still allow us to browse the file system using file:///c:/windows/ which can then lead to all sorts of shenanigans obviously

Server 2016 and Citrix 7.12 Platinum. FF and Chrome are required for compatibility reasons

Comment: Not a security question but a product config question. And I get hits when I google your question: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-admins/rnVYw_0aq8A

Comment: Many thanks for moving, my rational was that as I was using the path to get to PowerShell.exe and brake out of the Citrix session, this was a security related issue. The Chrome advice looks promising, but Firefox less so, I'll test and report back.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome you may use the Policy List of
[URLBlacklist](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#URLBlacklist):

> This policy prevents the user from loading web pages from blacklisted URLs. The blacklist provides a list of URL patterns that specify which URLs will be blacklisted.

You may also wish to disable file-selection dialogs using
[AllowFileSelectionDialogs](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AllowFileSelectionDialogs).